# Converting a function iterating over rows to apply method pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, apply

I have a function, which I am running over the rows of a dataframe one by one. I would like to convert it somehow to pandas apply method or something similar, and hoping to achieve a performance boost.

So the dataframe looks like this:

```
df
       object_id  ...                        param_dict
8804       15563  ...                         {81: 2.0}
8805       15566  ...                         {81: 2.0}
8806       15553  ...                         {81: 2.0}
8808       15531  ...                         {81: 2.0}
8811       15639  ...                         {81: 2.0}
...          ...  ...                               ...
16525       1158  ...  {4: 9963.302345992126, 46: 92.4}
16526       1156  ...               {4: -0.0, 46: 67.5}
16527       1089  ...                 {4: -0.0, 46: 76}
16528        898  ...               {4: -0.0, 46: 67.5}
16531        893  ...               {4: -0.0, 46: 67.5}
[1333 rows x 8 columns]
```

and the function:

```
def function(df):
    # running over the index of the dataframe
    for index in df.index:

        # running over the keys of the dataframe['param_dict'] dictionaries
        for key in df['param_dict'][index]:
            if df['param_dict'][index][key] == 0:
                continue

            if key in [4, 27]:
                print(df['name'][index], df['param_dict'][index][key], 1)

            elif key in [46, 28, 29]:
                print(df['name'][index], df['param_dict'][index][key], 2)

            else:
                print(df['name'][index], df['param_dict'][index][key], 3)

    return None
```

So at the moment, the first for-loop runs 1333 times, and depending the keys of the dictionary the inside for-loop also runs couple of times. **Is there a way me to convert this function to apply method somehow, so that at least I do not need to run over the index?**

Here is the simple dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'param_dict': [{4: 0, 1: 4}, {46: True}, {35: False, 25: 0}]})
```

Comment: If you could give a workable subset of the data, it would be a great help to find a solution.

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes I added the simple data set, and u should be able to copy-paste the function(df)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that is applied to every row in a pandas dataframe, modifies the row and returns a new version of it to the df, for instance:

```
def func(row):
  row['key1'] = row['key1'] + row['key2']
  return row
```

And then you can apply it over the index:

```
df = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: ty @Daniel, but I already know how to use the apply function. However what I looking for is a little bit more complex than this..